# mutiple images not displaying in custom tab form in admin grid in magento2

Tags: magento2, admin

how to display the uploaded image in the custom tab in admin grid in that single image is coming but multiple images are not coming in database multiple image name are stored through that I want to display the image in custom tab 
screenshot

[image]

**info.php**

```
$fieldset->addField(
        'image',
        'image',
        [
            'name'        => 'image',
            'label'    => __('image'),
            'required'     => true

        ]
    );
```